# Oracle APEX - making hyperlink bold inside the dynamic pl/sql region

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a dynamic PL/SQL region that displays a couple of hyperlink. Is there a way to make one of them display in bold based on the current page number? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example; you'd apply the `<b>` HTML tag to make the hyperlink *bold* if page number is (for example) 44.

```
begin
  htp.prn('<html>');
    htp.prn('<head>');
      htp.prn('<body>');
        htp.prn('<p>');
          htp.prn('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
        htp.prn('</p>');

        htp.prn('<p>');
          htp.prn(case when :APP_PAGE_ID = 44 then '<b>' end);   --> this ...
          htp.prn('<a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>');
          htp.prn(case when :APP_PAGE_ID = 44 then '</b>' end);  --> ... and this
        htp.prn('</p>');
      htp.prn('</body>');
    htp.prn('</head>');
  htp.prn('</html>');
end;
```

Comment: Or use htp.bold()

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Scott. Her Grace will certainly be satisfied, being able to pick an option she finds the most suitable.

Comment: Well, if you're going to go the probable long way around and use HTP, you might as well make it look more readable, and use the suite of supplied functions.

Comment: Thank you! this is great